# Лучший способ определения дистанции

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем доброго времени суток! Делаю игру для телефона и возник вопрос с определением дистанции от множества объектов до игрока. Т.е. у меня на сцене есть много объектов и один игрок, нужно выполнить действие при приближении игрока на определенную дистанцию.

Не накладна ли будет подобная проверка `float distance = (player.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude` на каждом из объектов раз в 0.5 секунд?

Или лучше дать объектам Circle Collider2D и проверять через OnTriggerEnter2d()

А если объектов много, примерно 50, то какой способ лучше?
Или может вы знаете другие способы?

Comment: 50 - это не много, да и зачем информация на экране о расстоянии одновременно до 50 объектов? Считайте только то что надо показывать или реально использовать, остальное не считайте.

Comment: У меня получается, что есть подземелье разбитое на комнаты, а в каждой комнате по 8 монстров и вот каждый из этих монстров просчитывает дистанцию до игрока, чтобы начать к нему двигаться. А если объектов(монстров) будет 100, то не накладно раз в 0.5 сек высчитывать будет?

Comment: Если вас волнует производительность при росте количества врагов,  просто предложу такое: разбить карту на какие то квадранты/сектора/или как у вас комнаты и проверять расстояние только для тех монстров, которые в том же или в смежном секторе находятся.

Answer (score 1):

Длина вектора вычисляется так: `√(x²+y²+z²)` или `sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)`. Работает для 3d, 2d, 1d, 100d... Самая тяжелая операция это вычисление квадратного корня.

Для вычисления длины вектора используется свойство `pointA.magnitude` или `Vector3.Distance(pointA, pointB)`, это одни и те же вычисления.

Но что бы сравнить длины, вычислять квадратный корень не имеет смысла, можно сравнить сами квадраты, результат будет тот-же. Для этого есть свойство `pointA.sqrMagnitude` (`x*x+y*y+z*z`).

```
if (pointA.sqrMagnitude < pointB.sqrMagnitude)
...
float sqrTriggerDistance = triggerDistance*triggerDistance;
if (pointA.sqrMagnitude < sqrTriggerDistance)
```

Эта операция не особо затратная, два притопа, три умножить, вычисляй хоть тысячу раз каждый кадр.

На дополнительных проверках типа, если длина длиньше самой длинной оси то в этом нет смысла

```
if (Mathf.Max(pointA.x, Mathf.Max(pointA.y, pointA.z)) < triggerDistance &&
    pointA.sqrMagnitude < sqrTriggerDistance)
```

можешь больше потерять, но это нужно тестить с `stopwatch`.